# How to display a link inserted in Google Calendar on Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

After creating an event in Google Calendar, I inserted a link in the description box. How do I use apps script to display links properly in Google Sheets? When the link inserted in Google Calendar was linked to Google Sheet, it was displayed as shown below.

```
<a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1za_UIFwAgpVuN080jkjfacPGUWT3Eul--/view?usp=drive_link">Link</a>
```

I want it to display like this "[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1za_UIFwAgpVuN080jakjfcPGUWT3Eul--/view?usp=drive_link)" on google sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a rich value. and then set it.

```
function setURL(){

  var range = getActiveSheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A2");
  var richValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
   .setText("More information")
   .setLinkUrl("https://example.com")
   .build();
 range.setRichTextValue(richValue);
}
```